# Create smoke like affect using hair particles

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, force-fields

I'm trying to see if this effect can be achieved the same effect from the film mama(2013) the same way her hair moves in the film I tried experimenting with force field but I'm not really seeing the results.

Comment: It is impossible to know what effect you are trying to achieve with no examples and no indication as to what you have tried so far?

Comment: The hair is floating around the head, like it is under water. It is a horror movie so no beauty makeup, [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKFQfaDL9gQ) would be the effect.

Comment: Yes that is the look I'm trying to achieve the underwater effect would I use the fluid simulator?